Transparency not combining opacity between two translucent objects
I know that the title may seem confusing, but I don't know how else to explain it.
I am trying to make an "acrylic" material, but when I have two faces of transparency intersect, the transparency effects don't change, making it look like some of the "acrylic" isn't there. It's difficult to explain, so I'll just show some screenshots:


Thank you for your help. Is there any way to solve this? (and make it look more realistic?)
EDIT:
Here's the file, and the nodes/settings



Please [edit] your question and show how your shader is made. Additionally, you can also share a sample file on https://blend-exchange.com and insert the link in your question.

I've edited the post to include this. Hope that helps

Rendering technologies considerations
Prior to Eevee-Next, legacy Eevee used to have an old school way to handle transparency. And the default settings were basically to have none of it.

The default "Opaque" makes your rendered preview or material preview (powered by Eevee) looks as if it shows only what is visible from the front.
Try setting it to "Alpha Blend", and already it would at least let you see what's behind the front surfaces:

But, to be honest, Eevee Legacy being what it is, anything related to transparency, volumetric, refraction, ... Will be a chore at least.
You will also struggle with z-fighting a lot. When surfaces are on each other, Eevee will not know for sure which one to render in front of the other, and give you this kind of mess:

Moving your faces a bit away from each other will help in that regard.
Acrylic shader
When trying to replicate a matter, it's always good to wonder what its features are and how it translates into a shader in Blender.
Acrylic panes are basically a specific kind of plastic. The surface is most often smooth with slight imperfection. The "inside", the "body" of the matter, makes the color changes and diffuses light, making it more or less blurry when looked through.
That means, we need dielectric (non-metallic) surface reflections with little roughness and imperfections, slight tinting, refraction, and the inside must look more or less blurry and absorbing.
Using the Principled BSDF
If you want to stick to the Principled BSDF (which has the advantage of being familiar to use and easier to export or reproduce in other modern render engines), it would mean metallic at 0, transmission at 1, a little bit of Transmission Roughness to mimic the volumetric blurriness, maybe a texture plugged into the Roughness and normal for slight surface imperfections.
Which results to this in Legacy Eevee:

In Cycles, you can get very nice results with the same shader but lower Alpha:

Custom Shader
A custom shader mixing a Glass BSDF with a Translucent BSDF by the Fresnel factor could be used. Still with some roughness and normal texturing if wanted.
The result in Eevee isn't much different:

But it's quite a change in Cycles:

